# Velocity in Unity 2D How to get velocity of object without rigidbody

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, velocity, gameobject, rigid-bodies

By using method `transform.translate(Vector3.left * 5f * Time.Deltatime;` does this change the velocity of a  gameobject with a rigidbody ,because in my case it doesnt work.Is there a way i can move an object so the velocity changes .If not is there any way to measure velocity of an object without having a Rigidbody attached to it. Thanks.

Comment: `translate` lets an object "jump" to that position but the `RigidBody` component keeps its current velocity. You can however get the velocity as e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52581610/7111561) and than apply it to the [RigidBody.velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can measure the velocity vector like this:

```
Vector3 pos, velocity;

void Awake()
{
    pos = transform.position;
}

void Update()
{
    velocity = (transform.position - pos) / Time.deltaTime;
    pos = transform.position;
}
```

Comment: Just adding that this gives you actually a velocity vector. If you want the real velocity you can use `velocity.magnitude`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Transform.hasChanged](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-hasChanged.html)

```
if (!this.transform.hasChanged)
{
    print("Player is not moving");
}
transform.hasChanged = false;
```